# Uploading an image as featured image from frontend form

Tags: images, uploads

I have built a little form in a frontend page.

I want user to create new post in a specific sort of post (listing).

All fields are OK but only upload file is not working.
Could you please tell me what is wrong with [this code]

Here is the full code :

**Processing form fields code**

```
<?php if ( ! isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
/*
   Template Name: New Event Page
*/
/*
   for uploading media file as featured image post
*/
    function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id , $attach_id);

    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
    }

/* Options for template pages */

    $et_ptemplate_settings = array();
    $et_ptemplate_settings = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'et_ptemplate_settings',true) );

    $fullwidth = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] : false;

/* Checking errors and data forms */

$et_regenerate_numbers = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_regenerate_numbers'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_regenerate_numbers'] : false;

$et_error_message = '';
$et_contact_error = false;



    /* Checking captcha codes */
    if ( isset($_POST['et_eventorm_submit']) ) {
        if ( !isset($_POST['et_contact_captcha']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_captcha']) ) {
            $et_error_message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('Make sure you entered the captcha. ','Explorable') . '</p>';
            $et_contact_error = true;
        } else if ( $_POST['et_contact_captcha'] <> ( $_SESSION['et_first_digit'] + $_SESSION['et_second_digit'] ) ) {
            $et_numbers_string = $et_regenerate_numbers ? esc_html__('Numbers regenerated.','Explorable') : '';
            $et_error_message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('You entered the wrong number in captcha. ','Explorable') . $et_numbers_string . '</p>';

            if ($et_regenerate_numbers) {
                unset( $_SESSION['et_first_digit'] );
                unset( $_SESSION['et_second_digit'] );
            }

            $et_contact_error = true;

        /* Checking custom fields filled */
        } else if ( empty($_POST['et_contact_title_event']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_desc_event']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_infosupp_event']) ){
            $et_error_message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('Make sure you fill all fields. ','Explorable') . '</p>';
            $et_contact_error = true;
        }

} else {
    $et_contact_error = true;
    if ( isset($_SESSION['et_first_digit'] ) ) unset( $_SESSION['et_first_digit'] );
    if ( isset($_SESSION['et_second_digit'] ) ) unset( $_SESSION['et_second_digit'] );
}

if ( !isset($_SESSION['et_first_digit'] ) ) $_SESSION['et_first_digit'] = $et_first_digit = rand(1, 15);
else $et_first_digit = $_SESSION['et_first_digit'];

if ( !isset($_SESSION['et_second_digit'] ) ) $_SESSION['et_second_digit'] = $et_second_digit = rand(1, 15);
else $et_second_digit = $_SESSION['et_second_digit'];

/* Formatting data to update in WP_DB */
if( !$et_contact_error ){

$eventcategory= $_POST['cat'];



// Add the content of the form to $post as an array
$post = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST['et_contact_title_event'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['et_contact_infosupp_event'],
    //'post_category'   => $_POST['et_contact_cat_event'],  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'post_status'   => 'draft',         // Choose: publish, preview, future, etc.
    'post_type' => 'listing'  // Use a custom post type if you want to
);

$pid = wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function


if ($_FILES) {
array_reverse($_FILES);
$i = 0;//this will count the posts
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            if ($i == 0) $set_feature = 1; //if $i ==0 then we are dealing with the first post
            else $set_feature = 0; //if $i!=0 we are not dealing with the first post
                    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid, $set_feature);
            echo $i++; //count posts
            }
} 


/* Linking list category with the post */
wp_set_object_terms($pid, $eventcategory,'listing_type');


$et_error_message = '<p>' . esc_html__('Merci pour le nouvel evenement!') . '</p>' ;


} ?>
```

**Form code**

```
                            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>" method="post" id="et_contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div id="et_contact_left">

                                    <!-- post event title -->
                                    <p class="clearfix">
                                        <label for="et_contact_title_event" class="et_contact_form_label">Titre de l'&eacute;v&eacute;vement sportif</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="et_contact_title_event" value="Titre de l'&eacute;v&eacute;vement sportif" id="et_contact_title_event" class="input" />
                                    </p>

                                    <!-- post event description -->
                                    <p class="clearfix">
                                        <label for="et_contact_desc_event" class="et_contact_form_label">Description br&egrave;ve de l'&eacute;v&eacute;vement sportif</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="et_contact_desc_event" value="Description br&egrave;ve de l'&eacute;v&eacute;vement sportif" id="et_contact_desc_event" class="input" />
                                    </p>

                                     <!-- post event category -->
                                    <p class="clearfix">
                                        <fieldset class="et_contact_cat_event" name="et_contact_cat_event">
                                            <label for="et_contact_cat_event" class="">Cat&eacute;gorie de l'&eacute;v&eacute;nement sportif : </label>
                                                <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=10&taxonomy=listing_type&hide_empty=0&value_field=name' ); ?>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </p>

                                    <!-- post event more info -->
                                    <p class="clearfix">
                                        <label for="et_contact_infosupp_event" class="et_contact_form_label">Informations compl&eacute;mentaires</label>
                                        <textarea class="input" id="et_contact_infosupp_event" name="et_contact_infosupp_event">Informations compl&eacute;mentaires</textarea>
                                    </p>


                                <!-- post event featured image -->
                                <p class="clearfix">
                                    <!-- images -->
                                    <fieldset class="images">
                                    <label for="file">Image &agrave; la une</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" >
                                    </fieldset>
                                </p>    

                                </div> <!-- #et_contact_left -->

                                <div id="et_contact_right">
                                    <p class="clearfix">
                                        <?php
                                            esc_html_e('Captcha: ','Explorable');
                                            echo '<br/>';
                                            echo esc_attr($et_first_digit) . ' + ' . esc_attr($et_second_digit) . ' = ';
                                        ?>
                                        <input type="text" name="et_contact_captcha" value="<?php if ( isset($_POST['et_contact_captcha']) ) echo esc_attr($_POST['et_contact_captcha']); ?>" id="et_contact_captcha" class="input" size="2" />
                                    </p>
                                </div> <!-- #et_contact_right -->

                                <div class="clear"></div>


                                <input type="hidden" name="et_eventorm_submit" value="et_contact_proccess" />

                                <input type="reset" id="et_contact_reset" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Reset','Explorable'); ?>" />
                                <input class="et_contact_submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Submit','Explorable'); ?>" id="et_contact_submit" />

                                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'et-contact-form-submit', '_wpnonce-et-contact-form-submitted' ); ?>
                            </form>
            <?php } ?>
                    </div> <!-- end #et-contact -->
```

As mentionned above, all the fields are passing into the database (wp_posts table & wp_postmeta).

Only the file to upload doesn't work ! I'm becoming made ! I followed this article to build my form : [upload featured image from front end using wordpress add media button](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134451/upload-featured-image-from-front-end-using-wordpress-add-media-button)

Any suggestion or correction would be appreciated :'(

Comment: Please post the relevant code inside your question.

Comment: I have put the code, thank you for your support :-)

Comment: It is like when i submit the form, there is nothing in the file... variable for $file is empty or something like that... Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem.

Problem was in a .js file. This code is causing the problem :

```
$et_contact_form.live('submit', function() {
    et_contact_error = false;
    et_message = '<ul>';

    $et_inputs.removeClass('et_contact_error');

    $et_inputs.each(function(index, domEle){
        if ( jQuery(domEle).val() === '' || jQuery(domEle).val() === jQuery(this).siblings('label').text() ) {
            jQuery(domEle).addClass('et_contact_error');
            et_contact_error = true;

            var default_value = jQuery(this).siblings('label').text();
            if ( default_value == '' ) default_value = et_ptemplates_strings.captcha;

            et_message += '<li>' + et_ptemplates_strings.fill + ' ' + default_value + ' ' + et_ptemplates_strings.field + '</li>';
        }
        if ( (jQuery(domEle).attr('id') == 'et_contact_email') && !et_email_reg.test(jQuery(domEle).val()) ) {
            jQuery(domEle).removeClass('et_contact_error').addClass('et_contact_error');
            et_contact_error = true;

            if ( !et_email_reg.test(jQuery(domEle).val()) ) et_message += '<li>' + et_ptemplates_strings.invalid + '</li>';
        }
    });

    if ( !et_contact_error ) {
        $href = jQuery(this).attr('action');

        $et_contact_container.fadeTo('fast',0.2).load($href+' #et-contact', jQuery(this).serializeArray(), function() {
            $et_contact_container.fadeTo('fast',1);
        });
    }

    et_message += '</ul>';

    if ( et_message != '<ul></ul>' )
        $et_contact_message.html(et_message);

    return false;
})
```

And what is causing the trouble exactly :

```
if ( !et_contact_error ) {
        $href = jQuery(this).attr('action');

        $et_contact_container.fadeTo('fast',0.2).load($href+' #et-contact', jQuery(this).serializeArray(), function() {
            $et_contact_container.fadeTo('fast',1);
        });
    }
```

I think the fact that this javascript is refreshing the form without complete refresh page is causing that the file is not received by the server via POST methode

Am I right ?

Do you have any clue to solve the JS thing to include the file upload ?